# Writing vectors to shared memory

Tags: vector, stl, ipc, shared-memory

I'm new to `STL` containers, and from what I saw, writing vectors to shared memory and reading off from it seems to be a bit of a bother.

For certain reasons, libraries like `Boost:InterProcess` are not an option. So I need to write the shared memory and allocator myself, for a vector of a complex type, but am not sure how to go on about it.

If someone could give me an example of how it's done, or a link where I can see a code example or an explanation, I'd be grateful. THanks

**EDIT**
I've a vector defined as

```
vector <SERVER_INFO_TYPE *> m_serverVecotr
```

where `SERVER_INFO_TYPE` is itself a `structure` containing `CStrings` etc..

Comment: If you are able, I'd strongly suggest going with MS's C++ multi-threading support. They've taken a lot of the pain out of thread safety. As far as the vector class they provide you can find that, as well as a simple example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd504906(v=vs.110).aspx#vector

Comment: You have a vector of pointers, pointing to structures that in turn contain pointers to still more heap-allocated memory. Realize that it's pointless (no pun intended) to write pointers to shared memory: those pointers are meaningless in the address space of the other process with which the memory is shared. You will have to serialize the whole thing into a single flat memory block containing no pointers (it may contain self-referential offsets). That means no `CString`s or anything like that.

Comment: Got the part about the Pointers and address space violation across processes. Think I understood the part about the serialization and memory block too. Have to implement it. Didn't get the Self referential offsets part. And how would I substitute `CString` in this case? Could you explain a bit further, please?

Comment: Imagine that you need to save all that data to a file, then later read it back. Design the on-disk file format. Then use that same format to serialize to shared memory.

Comment: Ah, OK. Got that. Thanks a lot. I'll try and implement it.